# I have an array of array and passing it to a function in scala but getting errors

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array, haversine

I need to implement a distance search code.My input is as follows in the CSV.

```
Proprty_ID,  lat,    lon
123,    33.84,  -118.39
234,    35.89,  -119.48
345,    35.34,  -119.39
```

I have a haversine formula which takes 2 coordinates `(lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)` and return the distance. Let say:

```
val Distance: Double = haversine(x1:Double, x2:Double, y1:Double, y2:Double)
```

I need to find out the distance of each property with each other. so the output will look like this.

```
Property_ID1, Property_ID2, distance
123,123,0
123,234,0.1
123,345,0.6
234,234,0
234,123,0.1
234,345,0.7
345,345,0
345,123,0.6
345,234,0.7
```

How can I implement this in Scala?

```
import math._

object Haversine {
   val R = 6372.8  //radius in km

   def haversine(lat1:Double, lon1:Double, lat2:Double, lon2:Double)={
      val dLat=(lat2 - lat1).toRadians
      val dLon=(lon2 - lon1).toRadians

      val a = pow(sin(dLat/2),2) + pow(sin(dLon/2),2) * cos(lat1.toRadians) * cos(lat2.toRadians)
      val c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
      R * c
   }

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      println(haversine(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40))
  }
}

class SimpleCSVHeader(header:Array[String]) extends Serializable {
  val index = header.zipWithIndex.toMap
  def apply(array:Array[String], key:String):String = array(index(key))
}

val lat1=33.84
val lon1=-118.39
val csv = sc.textFile("file.csv") 
val data = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim)) 
val header = new SimpleCSVHeader(data.take(1)(0)) // we build our header with the first line
val rows = data.filter(line => header(line,"lat") != "lat") // filter the header out

// I will do the looping for all properties here but I am trying to get the map function right for one property at least
val distances = rows.map(x => haversine(x.take(1)(0).toDouble,x.take(1)(1).toDouble, lat1,lon1)`
```

Now this should give me the distances for all the properties from `(lat1, lon1)`. I know it's not right but I am not able to think from here.

Comment: What have you written or tried so far? We'd love to help but writing the code for you is not the purpose of this site. Instead, if you were to present the code you've written but doesn't work, we could help make it work.

Comment: Here is the code I have got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to break it down into steps. Given data like:

```
  val rows = List(Array("123", "33.84", "-118.39"),
                  Array("234", "35.89", "-119.48"),
                  Array("345", "35.34", "-119.39"))
```

First convert the types:

```
  val typed = rows.map{ case Array(id, lat, lon) => (id, lat.toDouble, lon.toDouble)}
```

Then generate the combinations:

```
  val combos = for {
    a <- typed
    b <- typed
  } yield (a,b)
```

Then generate an output line for each combination:

```
  combos.map{ case ((id1, lat1, lon1), (id2, lat2, lon2)) 
     => id1 + "," + id2 + "," + haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)} foreach println
```

Comment: Thanks much DNA. It is working. However do you know if I can apply the same functions on RDD in spark. I am creating the RDD of input data from CSV. But it is failing on typed.collect().

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question, with your current Spark code, so we can better see what the problem is.